# Etimología de "bellaco"

Tags: etimología, adjetivos

Según el DLE, el [adjetivo "bellaco"](https://dle.rae.es/bellaco?m=form) es de origen incierto.

De todas formas, me pregunto: ¿hay hipótesis sobre su origen?

A propósito del hecho que la palabra italiana "vigliacco" procede etimológicamente del español "bellaco", el [*Grande dizionario della lengua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000871.jpg) indica lo siguiente sobre el origen de "bellaco":

> di origine incerta (secondo alcuni, dal lat. *villus* 'pelo', nel senso di 'peloso' e poi di 'indolente, villano'; secondo altri, da *bellaquería*, prestito dal catal. *bacallaria* a sua volta da *bacallar* 'vigliacco',
> ma propriamente 'contadino di condizione media', che è dal fr. ant. *bachelar* 'giovane non ancora cavaliere')

Es decir, explica que el vocablo es, en efecto, de origen incierto, pero que según algunos podría venir del latín *villus* "vello", con el significado de "peludo" y, más adelante de "indolente, vulgar o maleducado" (lo de "vulgar o maleducado" es mío y no estoy del todo segura: la palabra italiana "villano" tiene diferentes significados). Otra hipótesis es que proceda de *bellaquería*, préstamo del catalán *bacallaria*, que proviene a su vez de *bacallar* "vil", pero propiamente "campesino de condición media", que a su vez viene del francés antiguo *bachelar* "joven que aún no es caballero".

¿Existe alguna fuente que corrobore estas u otras hipótesis sobre el origen de "bellaco"?

Comment: Me ha hecho mucha gracia lo de "bacallar" en catalán porque es una palabra homófona de "bacallà", que significa "bacalao" y he visto muchas veces escrito el nombre del pescado en catalán, erróneamente, "bacallar".

Answer (score 2):

En su *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico*, Corominas confirma que, en efecto, su origen es incierto. De las diferentes hipótesis, la que Corominas considera más verosímil es que proceda del verbo *bellacar*, que a su vez viene de un verbo del vasco oriental. Lo explica de este modo:

> BELLACO, de origen incierto, acaso emparentado con el cat. ant. *bacallar* íd., al que se cree procedente de una palabra céltica conservada en formas algo diferentes, mas para el castellano esto es improbable pues su forma es ya muy alejada; en el S. XIV encontramos un verbo *bellacar* en el sentido de 'infamar, deshonrar' lo cual coincide con el vasco oriental *bilhakatu* 'arruinar, maltratar, tironear' y en zonas muy conservadoras 'arrancar los pelos, tirar de ellos', derivado de *bilho* 'pelo, cabello', luego es verosímil suponer que *bellaco* se creara en ambientes bilingües vasco-castellanos como derivado de aquel verbo denominando a gente baja y tabernaria que anda mucho a la greña, a la antigua manera vasca.

Curiosamente esta es la hipótesis que tiene que ver con el latín *vĭllus*: al final del artículo Corominas explica que el vasco *bilho* viene del latín *vĭllus*.

Los primeros usos documentados de *bellaco* se encuentran en estas fuentes:

> Med. S. XIII, *Las Siete Partidas* de Alfonso X el Sabio; J. Ruiz, Arcipreste de Hita, *Libro de Buen Amor*; *La Gran Conquista de Ultramar*; inscripción castellana de Granada de 1332-54.

La otra hipótesis que aparece en la pregunta, es decir, que proceda de *bellaquería*, que vendría por metátesis del catalán *bacallaria*, que proviene a su vez de *bacallar*, ha sido estudiada a fondo por este autor que, de todas formas, ha encontrado elementos suficientes como para descartarla.

Otra hipótesis que Corominas también ha examinado a fondo es que sea de origen céltico, procedente de alguna variante de *BACCLACCUS, emparentado con el irlandés antiguo *bachlach* 'criado', 'sujeto tosco o campesino' y con sus afines bretón
*begleg* y ky.<sup>1</sup> *baglog* 'sacerdote', que derivan del irlandés *bachall*, ky. *bagl* 'báculo', 'cayado', que a su vez son préstamos del latín *ba(c)culum*. Pero a Corominas esta hipótesis le parece aún más inverosímil por razones fonéticas.

---

<sup>1. No he conseguido averiguar qué significa la abreviatura ky.</sup>

Comment: Dados que otros usos que hace Corominas de la abreviatura ky. corresponden a palabras en galés (hogi = afilar) quizás corresponda a "galés" o a "protocéltico".

Comment: The only Celtic language which starts with K is Kernewek (Cornish) but that contains no Y. However the Germans call Welsh Kymraeg (in Welsh Cymraeg) so if Corominas was using a German source that might be the answer but it does seem super-unlikely.

Comment: @mdewey: Corominas cites Pokorny's *Keltologie* in this article, so it could perfectly be.

Answer (score 1):

La versión abreviada del Corominas indica que "... es más  verosímil  suponer  que  ...  se  creara ...  como derivado  del  verbo  bellacar  de  origen  vascuence."

Comment: @Charo: Oir es obedecer !

Comment: ¡Uy, Felix, has reducido tu respuesta a tan poca cosa que me parecía mejor la de antes!